# Why is Academia only for higher education?

Tags: discussion

High School students need help too and I don't understand why only higher education matters. Why can't academia support the questions of high school students too?

Comment: high school is simply not considered to be part of academia, in the sense that academics use the word "academia". different subject entirely.

Comment: Downvoted - this looks more like an advertisement for OP's Area51 proposal than an honest question.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni ironically I didn't know the OP had made such a proposal until I read your comment. Also it looks like the OP made it after receiving an answer on this, so unless this was a devious ploy this was not intended as any kind of advertisement to begin with.

Comment: @djechlin OP's proposal is linked in a comment below, and they also gave an answer recommending it (the answer was later deleted by a moderator) Unfortunately I cannot check the exact time of the proposal creation on Area51, but this *does* look like what you call a "devious ploy" to me: OP's "I have just proposed one" comment is their first Area51 proposal, and it comes 2 minutes after ff524's suggestion of creating one. That seems barely the time to locate Area51 without a weblink, check how it works, searching for an existing similar proposal, make a new Area51 account and a new proposal.

Answer (score 28):

**TL;DR**: It's not that high school questions are unimportant. But they target a different group of experts than questions about higher education, so they need a different site.

The Stack Exchange model is based on the idea that a high-quality Q&A site should have a dedicated user base of experts in that subject, who spend time contributing high-quality answers to the site.

The group of "experts on academia and higher education" and "experts on high school" are distinct groups with not much overlap. So it makes sense to have separate SE sites for higher education and high school - the expert user base will be different. Academia is the site for higher education. There is currently no SE site about high school, but you can check Area 51 to see if there's a proposed site, and propose one if there isn't.

Comment: Thank you and I am aware of that. I have just proposed one.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92854/high-school?referrer=sVPX4oDZwMD9Q7-mfO81Tw2

Comment: @KeyanKazemian if you agree with this answer, how about to accept that?

Comment: Sadly it looks like all proposals for things like "highschool" or "K-12 education" stackexchanges have fizzled. I am very surprised by this, because I think the pool of potential users must be larger than even that of this site, and it really seems like there ought to be a need for it.