# Are questions related to college preparation on topic?

Tags: discussion

I had a question about the existence of college prep style schools in Europe, but in reading the on-topic list it's not clear to me whether I can ask such a question.

[This question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/why-is-academia-only-for-higher-education) here clearly indicates that only higher education is on topic, but since college prep style high schools clearly prepare students *for* college and academia, it's unclear to me whether or not they should be off-topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic says "Please **do not ask**":

> about **[undergraduate admissions](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300)**,

> about **[education outside an academic setting](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2059/7734)**, i.e., in high schools or similar.

Prep schools are education outside an academic setting, as they are a type of high school. Questions about prep schools as related to undergraduate admissions are also explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Thanks!  I think the use of the word "academic" in this sense is what was confusing me, as I often find it associated with all levels of education, not just academia.

Comment: @Michael If you wish you can drop your question in [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/the-ivory-tower), maybe someone can give you some indication anyway. However, beware that most Europeans probably don't have a clue on what a "college prep style school" is, so you need to explain a bit the topic.

Comment: By the way, the reason for this is that "career academics" (e.g., professors) have no real expertise to offer when it comes to high schools or undergraduate admissions (or college prep style schools). We would be only marginally more informed than the public at large. Perhaps some day they will open a new stack dedicated to college admissions and high schools.